# Function call in Google App Engine - Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In `main.py` I have a display code that repeats several times. So I created a `f1.py` and placed the code in `f1.py` as a function `display(query)` and I am calling it from `main.py` as `f1.display(query)`.

But `display(query)` has the line

```
self.response.out.write(
# some code
)
```

and I get the error message:

```
self.response.out.write(
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

I tried to import `from google.appengine.ext import webapp` inside the `display(query)` function but that did not help.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is a conventional name for the first argument passed to a class instance's methods.  A class instance will pass a reference to itself as the first argument to all of it's methods when they are called.  It's common practice to name the first parameter for instance methods `self`.

So, when you factored out part of your method's (presumably `get` or `post` on a sublcass of `webapp.RequestHandler`) functionality to another function, you can no longer refer to `self` and get the `response` property.

The easiest way to fix this would probably be to return the output you wish to write to the response in the function.  Then you can call `self.response.out.write` with your function's return value from within in the method as you did before the refactor.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. But I was hoping to include the entire display section in the function. This doesn't seem to be possible. Thanks.

Comment: @Zeynel You could pass 'self' to the function in question. Or, you could make the function a method of the handler class, instead of a function.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: Many thanks! `f1.display(query, self)` works. Now, knowing this, I will be able to put my navigation code in `f1` as well. Thanks again.